# Getting all the Raster pixel value from PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, raster2pgsql

I just uploaded the raster using following code,

```
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M raster.tif -F -t 100x100 public.raster_table | psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost -d raster
```

It takes around 15 min to upload to database. After complete the process, I checked the table using `SELECT * FROM public.raster_table;`. It has lots of  rows (around 4000) with serial rid. I want to view the each pixel value using `ST_value`. I already checked the [documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Value.html). In documentation, It provides following method to show all the pixel value.

```
SELECT x, y, ST_Value(rast, 1, x, y) As raster_val,
FROM raster_table CROSS JOIN
generate_series(1, 1000) As x CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 1000) As y
WHERE rid =  2 AND x <= ST_Width(rast) AND y <= ST_Height(rast);
```

But I am confused with `WHERE` condition. In example it only use `rid=2`. But I have lots of `rid`. Is this condition really checks the all the pixel value?

Comment: Could you explain why you would ever want to look at many times 10000 values?

Comment: Actually, I want to store the pixel value of each cell in a tabular form. and reclassify the raster values in 3 classes as low, medium and high. After that, I want to clip those raster with some administrative boundaries (district) and calculate the number of pixels having low, medium and high value as a form of three different column for each administrative boundary.

Comment: Then why not use ST_Reclass() to reclass the rasters to three values (1, 2, 3)? And then ST_ValueCount() to count the number of each value?

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. But I want to check the value first then I am planning to reclass and count the value. Thank you again I will do that.

Answer (score 4):

You can play around with `ST_PixelAsPoints` which returns almost exactly what you want:

```
select (ST_PixelAsPoints(rast)).* from raster_table
```

This will produce rows with geometry, value, x and y coordinate of each pixel in your `raster_table`. You can then, of course, include where clause to limit results only to some rasters (or geographic area, etc.)

Comment: The query takes lots of time to run. I am unable to see the result.

Comment: @Tekson It produces one row for each pixel in your raster dataset. As user30184 stated in previous answer, this can produce huge amount of rows, even for a relatively small raster...

Comment: Thank you for explanation. But I am still unable to see the result of query. May be my raster file is too big.

Comment: @Tekson Try to limit evaluated number of raster with where clause, something like "where rid = 1" should work. This will reduce total number of returned rows by limiting query to only one raster tile.

Comment: Ok thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You imported the raster as tiled and then each tile is getting its own row into the raster table and also an unique primary key value into the "rid" column.

Your query returns all the pixel values from the tile 2 of your raster. You should see that from the number of returned rows that is 100x100=10000. If you want to get values from all the pixels of the whole raster with one query you can either

1) Import data without tiling. Then you'll get just one row into the raster table. I assume it will have `rid=1` but you can check that from your database.

2) Import data as tiled but instead of `rid` use `filename`in the query.

`WHERE filename='raster_table'...`

Notice that the number of rows may be hard to handle: million rows for a raster with just 1000 x 1000 pixels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then you mean i have to remove `-t 100×100` while uploading?